# Android send notification from one device to another

Tags: android, notifications

any one knows how to send notification from one device to another in android !? For example, assuming that you have android app that a waiter get a new order, the kitchen app must get a notification about the new order !

Comment: You can use a socket for connection between two

Answer (score 0):

Just use a socket connection between two. and once received a message build a notification. 
You can connect them via bluetooth using BluetoothSockets. Android developer website has pretty good documentation on this.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Or if you'd rather (and have internet on both devices), you can use regular Socket's.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html for server side http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html for client side

If you have a large amount of data to transfer, internet sockets have a greater data capacity and will be faster. The other advantage is that there is no such thing as "out of range". You can connect the two devices wherever internet is available, whereas with bluetooth they have to be within bluetooth range of each other

Check this example Android Socket Example

Connecting to Bluetooth enabled device

Comment: thanks for replying .. Do i need a web server to deploy the socket solution ? Also i read that GCM could be a solution but i wonder if it is just about sending notifications from the developer(s) to the users not between the users of the app itself ?! Correct me if i am wrong ! Also if GCM could do that .. is it possible to configure a private notification between some of users ... i mean if i am one user and i want just send a notification to another user but not to all of users .. you know like some private room in old chat apps !

Comment: Yes everything is possible with GCM. You can manage it in your backend. There will be a id for each app